# React Native FlatList renders data character by character

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, asyncstorage

I have an array of objects like this:

```
[
  {"name":"XYZ","price":100,"instock":true},
  {"name":"OTR","price":945,"instock":true},
  {"name":"SLG","price":343,"instock":true}
]
```

The Flatlist `renderItem` displays it's each characters individually like this
[Output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kVk0.png)

My code is this

```
<View>
      {cartItems !== [] && (
        <FlatList
          data={cartItems}
          renderItem={({item}) => (
            <View>
              <Text>{item}</Text>
            </View>
          )}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        />
      )}
    </View>
```

I also tried this `renderItem={({item: {name, price}}) => ()}` and tried to print, it didn't display anything and when I logged it to console both of them were undefined

```
<View>
          {cartItems !== [] && (
            <FlatList
              data={[cartItems]}
              renderItem={({item}) => (
                <View>
                  <Text>{item}</Text>
                </View>
              )}
              keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
            />
          )}
        </View>
```

I also distructured the

But it rendered like this

```
[{"name":"XYZ","price":100,"instock":true},
 {"name":"OTR","price":945,"instock":true},
 {"name":"SLG","price":343,"instock":true}]
```

Here is the complete code

```
const ManageOrders = () => {


const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([]);

  const getItem = async () => {
    try {
      const item = await AsyncStorage.getItem('CartItem');
      // const items = JSON.parse(item); //This gave me error
      setCartItems(item);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getItem();
  }, []);

//   const data = JSON.parse(cartItems) //This gave me error
  return (
    <>
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.safeAreaView1} />
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.safeAreaView2}>
        <View>
          {cartItems !== [] && (
            <FlatList
              data={cartItems}
              renderItem={({item}) => (
                <View>
                  <Text>{item}</Text>
                </View>
              )}
              keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
            />
          )}
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </>
  );
};

export default ManageOrders;
```

Note: The data `cartItems` I got it from asyncstorage `AsyncStorage.getItem("CartItems")`
Can anyone help me with this please??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, the issue is I am not converting my API in JSON object when saving in REDUX.

```
let itemList = JSON.parse(response.data.response.dataList)
```

I did this and the error gone.

Answer (score 0):

You need to de-structure fields you want to display...

`renderItem={({item: { name, price }}) => (`

`<Text>{name}</Text>`

**In your first approach**
cause what you're doing by this -> `Text>{item}</Text>` is displaying the `.toString()` representation of your object `{"name":"XYZ","price":100,"instock":true}`

**Edit - 2nd Issue**

**In your second approach**
You passing `cardItems` into an array `data={[cartItems]}` ... so, your padding an array with a single item (cardItems) to your `FlatList` ... which results in a `.toString()` representation of that **array-of-objects** item

```
<View>
  {
  cardItems ? 
    <FlatList
      data={cartItems} // <--- Look at me
      renderItem={({ item: { name } }) => (
        <View>
          <Text>{name}</Text>
        </View>
      )}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
    />
  : <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}><Text>Loading</Text></View>}
</View>
```

**3rd Issue**

If you're getting `cardItems` through an async-operation ... then you need to check if it exists first ... not if it has items ... cause at first it'll be `undefined`, then you're condition `cartItems !== []` will evaludate to `false`, and your `FlatList` will be rendered...

**4th Issue :))**

You're getting your data from `AsyncStorage` ... it's stringified ... so don't forget to `JSON.parse` it first...

Comment: I did the same but name was undefined when I console.log() it also price was undefined

Comment: You are right @HendEl-Sahil, at first I was doing the same `{cartItems}` and if you try to access it like item.name it is undefined

Comment: If you're getting `cardItems` through an async-operation ... then you need to check if it exists first ... not if it has items ... cause at first it'll be `undefined`, then you're condition `cartItems !== []` will evaludate to `false`, and your `FlatList` will be rendered

Comment: data is comming from AsyncStorage, FlatList is rendering the data but the problem is that it is not rendering as expected, instead it renders each character of the data (even the brackets and qoutes)

Comment: `cartItems` is an array of objects, I did `JSON.parse(cartItems)` it gave me this error `SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected EOF`

Answer (score 0):

Its like looping through an array of objects, by saying {item} it means each object of the array, adding item to the text field will show the whole object as string ! i assumed that you want to show only a certain key from your object, ex: lets add the name to the text field:

```
 <View>
          {cartItems !== [] && (
            <FlatList
              data={[cartItems]}
              renderItem={({item}) => (
                <View>
                  <Text>{item.name}</Text>
                </View>
              )}
              keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
            />
          )}
        </View>
```

notice that we accessed the property name of the item object (objectName.propertyName)

Comment: item.name didn't display anything, then I logged it to console and saw that name in undefined

Comment: i see the problem now it is an array of objects not an object so if you said item[0].name i will get the name of the first object inside items array

Comment: Yes it is an array of objects that's what FlatList expects as its `data` prop
And I tried as you said `item[0].name` still got undefined :(

Comment: can you print out item and show me the results ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to access `item.name`
And check for `cartItems.length`

```js
import React from "react";
import { Button, FlatList, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

const cartItems = [
  { name: "XYZ", price: 100, instock: true },
  { name: "OTR", price: 945, instock: true },
  { name: "SLG", price: 343, instock: true }
];
function App() {
   if (cartItems.length > 0)
    return (
      <View>
        <FlatList
          data={cartItems}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <View>
              <Text>{item.name}</Text>
            </View>
          )}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index.toString()}
        />
      </View>
    );
}

export default App;
```